# EXT JS: Parent Panel with 2 sub panels

Tags: extjs

I am trying to build a Parent Panel, which will have 2 child panels. One panel will be a fixed small month view calendar, while the the other one would be customized large calendar. I am new with Ext JS and would appreciate any help that i could get.

Code examples would really help.

Comment: Did you have a look at examples at are available on the site: http://ext.ensible.com/deploy/dev/examples/ ?

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/calendar/index.html

Like Abdel said, the extJS examples are excelent